# R: summary() returns strange 1st Qu

Tags: r, summary

There's an exercise in Khan Academy' Probability and Statistics course on creating box-and-whisker plot. Here's [screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2bTRBdLgYUnMFB2NGNNb2tlQ1k/view?usp=sharing) representing correct solution.
But when I tried to check solution in R I got the following:

```
d <- c(11, 4, 1, 4, 2, 2, 6, 10, 5, 6, 0, 6, 3, 3)
summary(d)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   0.00    2.25    4.00    4.50    6.00   11.00
```

You can see 2.25 value for 1st Qu. But the correct value is 2. Any other values returned with summary() are correct. Any ideas why summary() returns wrong result?

Comment: This inspired me to ask a related question, and the response is a neat way to change the `type` used in `summary` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27221720/r-change-quantile-type-within-summary-default

Answer (score 5):

In a nutshell, there are many reasonable ways to compute quantiles. This is evidenced by the **nine** (!) different methods supported by the [`quantile`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/quantile.html) function.

`summary` is not wrong, it is just using a different method to the one you're expecting. It likely is using the default method 7 (called "type 7" in the help page). Like most other methods, it is performing linear interpolation between two adjacent values, 2 and 3.

You could try experimenting with the other methods by calling `quantile` with the appropriate `type` argument:

```
> quantile(s, type=1)
  0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
   0    2    4    6   11
```

Answer (score 3):

I had this very same issue as well. I think this is to do with the `type` of the quantile  calculation used.

This article explains it better than I can: http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/why-excel-has-multiple-quartile-functions-and-how-to-replicate-the-quartiles-from-r-and-other-statistical-packages/

To see examples:

```
quantile(d, probs=0.25)
25% 
2.25 
quantile(d, probs=0.25, type=6)
25% 
2
```