# r Change quantile 'type' within summary.default

Tags: r, quantile

**Question**

Following on from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27210745/r-summary-returns-strange-1st-qu/27210825#27210825) that asked about different quantile `types`, is it possible to change the `type` argument for `quantile` when using the `summary()` function?

For example, taking the dataset

```
d <- c(11, 4, 1, 4, 2, 2, 6, 10, 5, 6, 0, 6, 3, 3)
```

I'm happy that

```
quantile(d, probs=0.25, type=6)
```

and

```
quantile(d, probs=0.25, type=7)
```

produce different results, and that the default `type` used in `summary` is `type=7`. Is it possible to tell `summary` to use `type=6`?

**Notes / Output**

```
quantile(d, probs=0.25, type=6)
25% 
2

quantile(d, probs=0.25, type=7)
25% 
2.25

summary(d)
Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
0.00    2.25    4.00    4.50    6.00   11.00
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building on akrun's idea, you could modify `summary.default`

```
mySummary <- summary.default
body(mySummary)[[3]][[3]][[4]][[3]][[4]] <- 
    quote(qq <- stats::quantile(object, type = type))
formals(mySummary) <- c(formals(mySummary), type = 6)
```

And now the `type` is 6 by default

```
args(mySummary)
# function (object, ..., digits = max(3L, getOption("digits") - 
#     3L), type = 6) 
# NULL
mySummary(d)
#   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
#    0.0     2.0     4.0     4.5     6.0    11.0 
mySummary(d, type = 7)
#   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
#   0.00    2.25    4.00    4.50    6.00   11.00
```

And `mySummary` still maintains the properties of a `summary.default` object

```
attributes(mySummary(d))
# $names
# [1] "Min."    "1st Qu." "Median"  "Mean"    "3rd Qu." "Max."   
#
# $class
# [1] "summaryDefault" "table"
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm after. Thanks, and thanks @akrun too.